# How to add webpack style-loader nonce attribute to a craco config

Tags: javascript, webpack, create-react-app, craco

I'm trying to add the webpack [style-loader nonce attribute](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/#nonce) to a [craco config file](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#configuration-file), for a create-react-app, like this:

```js
// craco.config.js
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "style-loader",
              options: {
                attributes: {
                  nonce: "12345678",
                },
              },
            },
            "css-loader",
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

but that didn't work. Does anyone if this can be achieved with craco and how?.

Answer (score 7):

#### Problem

`craco` doesn't offer you to modify `module.rules` directly that way.

#### Solution

Instead it offers you `webpack.configure` method instead which takes following signature:

`configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => { return webpackConfig; }`

In order to override `style-loader` (only support `development` mode), you would need a few helper functions. Here is the idea for you:

```
// Import these helpers to figure out where the current loader located
const { getLoader, loaderByName } = require("@craco/craco");

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => { 
      
      if (env === 'development') {
        // your overridden `style-loader`
        const overrideOptions = {
          loader: "style-loader",
          options: {
            attributes: {
              nonce: "12345678",
            },
          },
        };

        // override `style-loader`
        const { isFound, match } = getLoader(webpackConfig, loaderByName('style-loader'));

        if (isFound) {
          match.parent[match.index] = overrideOptions;
        }
      }

      return webpackConfig; 
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: why only in development?

Comment: Also why do you go from the match, to the parent, back to the match with `match.parent[match.index]`? Why not just go `match.loader`? Serious question, I don't know

Comment: Good catch. I think you can try to set directly from `match.loader`.